# Spring Boot, Spring MVC JSON RequestBody: Unknown property ignored

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

we are developing a JSON web service to receive data via the @RequestBody annotation. In case a property is included in the request that does not match with the deserialized bean, we expect an HTTP 400 (Bad request) response, but instead the property is simply ignored. Here is an example:

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class TestController {

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/query")
  public void parse(@RequestBody Query query) {
    log.info("Received query: {}", query.toString());
  }
}


@Data
class Query {
  private String from;
  private String to;
}
```

When posting

```
{ "from" : "123", "to": "456", "foo" : "bar" }
```

we get a HTTP 200 response. How can we make Spring MVC return HTTP 400 in this case?

Any help or pointers are highly appreciated.

Note that this is different from this question: [How to return 400 HTTP error code when some property of a RequestBody parameter is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21172567/how-to-return-400-http-error-code-when-some-property-of-a-requestbody-parameter).

Since that question asks how to return 400 when an expected property is absent.

Comment: Have you tried:
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.Bad_request);

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpStatus.html

Comment: Spring should do this for me, in case deserialization fails.

Comment: Then I will just fly away again, I'm no expert at this area - Good luck

Comment: Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot? or plain spring mvc?

Comment: spring boot. Good point. I will update the question.

Comment: I would question whether it's a good idea to reject requests based on extraneous fields. Consider how this will impact your ability to roll back releases

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Put this into application.properties:

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES=true
```

Here are the relevant docs: [Customize the Jackson ObjectMapper](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper)

Comment: what do you mean by application properties ?detail your answer

Comment: application.properties is the main configuration file for Spring. You could also use application.yml.

Comment: Actually application.properties is something specific to Spring Boot, not Spring generally.

Answer (score 7):

You can reconfigure your Jackson (assuming you are using it) `ObjectMapper` to fail on unknown properties.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true);
```

In this case your unknown property will throw `JsonMappingException`  and you can introduce custom exception handler to return in this case Response 400.

Comment: Good point. But will this help? I should probably do this on the Spring Bean that Spring uses? I will try searching where I get that Bean from. Thanks.

Comment: Seems like here is some help: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper

Comment: Customization of the Spring Jackson deserialization Bean is done using an application property. See my answer below.

Answer (score -1):

How about this -

```
 private String to;
```

comparing against

```
{ "from" : "123", "foo" : "bar" }
```

I think you are comparing **to** against **foo**. So deserialization fails.

Comment: No. It does not fail. I am expecting it to fail, but it does not.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Validation for this Job , the validator will check if these fields are not null , if they are it spring will return `400 error bad request` so here is how you do it:

**In your Bean:**

```
public class A {
@NotNull
private String firstName;

   public String getFirstName() {
       return firstName;
   }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
       this.firstName = firstName;
   }
}
```

**In your Controler:**

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(path = "/rest")
public B treatRequest(@RequestBody @Validated A a) {...}
```

**In your Configuration File you should activate the validation like this**(probably you allready have it):

```
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

Comment: I am not asking to validate that some fields are not null. Instead I am asking to fail if fields are given, that are not expected. See my answer below.